# Startup script on EC2

Tags: git, shell, amazon-ec2, fedora

I've created a custom Amazon AMI (Fedora) runs a few scripts and then shuts down.

The problem with AMI's is that if my code changes there has to be a way for the AMI instance to get the latest scripts before it executes them.

I wrote a shell script & put it in `/etc/init.d/nt_startup`

To keep the code up to date, I execute a `git pull` shell script in my code repository and then execute the script.

The problem is, the `git pull` doesn't seem to run when an instance boots up, but the python script runs just fine. Not sure what I'm missing... here's the startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# ec2 Startup script for EC2 machines
#
# chkconfig: 345 99 02
# description: Script used to issue startup and shutdown commands.
#

if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
 /usr/scripts/code/git_latest
 python /usr/scripts/code/process.py
 exit
fi

if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
#nothing
exit
fi
```

The `/usr/scripts/code/git_latest` shell script looks like this:

```
#pulls in the latest code from the repository
cd /usr/scripts/code
sudo git pull
```

It should be pulling down the latest `process.py` script.

The strange thing is that if I ssh into my instance and execute the startup script manually (`/etc/init.d/nt_startup "start"`), the git script works just fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. After scouring the EC2 output I found this line:

"Starting ntstartup:  sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Apparently Fedora locks out non tty sudo commands.

A quick search led to the solution:

1. As root run "visudo."
2. Find the line with "Default requiretty" and comment it out (#Default requiretty)

Hope this is helpful for anyone else who runs into this issue.

Comment: Why are you using sudo? Startup scripts run as root anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a startup link in /etc/rc?.d.  You can use chkconfig(8) or ntsysv(8) to help you administer these directories.

Comment: The process.py script is being executed at start up... so I don't think that's the problem. It's just that the "git pull" is not being executed.

Comment: BTW, I did the above suggestions (# chkconfig: 345 99 02) and still no luck... I'll can think is that the git call is failing because the network hasn't been initialized or something?